# Makefile target global variable

Tags: makefile

I would like to have something like that:

```
PrintTarget:
    @echo Building $(TARGET)

SetRelTarget:   TARGET = Release
SetRelTarget:
    @echo Target is set.

BuildRel: SetRelTarget PrintTarget
```

But `TARGET` variable set in `SetRelTargetAs` is not a global.
My question is:

Is it possible to modify global variables inside the rule and use this modified value outside this rule?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set TARGET to release in BuildRel, then it should apply to all its prerequisites (although it's not global),

```
PrintTarget:
        @echo Building $(TARGET)

#SetRelTarget:   TARGET = Release
SetRelTarget:
        @echo Target is set to $(TARGET).

BuildRel: TARGET = Release
BuildRel: SetRelTarget PrintTarget
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is nothing variable in the code you can simply do this:

```
TARGET = Release

PrintTarget:
    @echo Building $(TARGET)

BuildRel: PrintTarget
```

Demo:

```
$ make BuildRel
Building Release
$ make TARGET=foo BuildRel
Building foo
```

If your use case is more complex please include more details.

Comment: I would like to use more targets and don't multiply the makefile procedures. Suppose that `PrintTarget` is a caomplicated and long but for different targets it differs only with `$(TARGET)` variable.